# Post request not working in MVC4 while using Jquery with Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I am now working on MVC4, trying to insert data into local server using Jquery Ajax and here I am facing problem. Post method in "**ValueController**" isn't being called. Please help.

This is my script in View.

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#createCustomer').click(function () {
        debugger;
        var id = $('#id').val();
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var city = $('#city').val();

        var cust = {
            Id: id,
            Name: name,
            City: city
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/api/values',
            data: JSON.stringify(cust),
            datatype: 'JSON',
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            Success: function (result) {
                success: true;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

My Post method in "**ValueController**"

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(Customer cust)
        {
            CustomerEntity.InsertValues(cust);
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, cust);
            return response;
        }
```

Here, ***Customer*** is model

Answer (score 0):

If your controller name is `ValueController` then

Change

`url: '/api/values',`

to

`url: '/api/value'`

Comment: if action name is Post why we do api/value?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, `api/controllername` , check http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: @Murali how could you assume OP using WebApi concept ? is there any reason?

Comment: @SivaRajini, look at `HttpResponseMessage` used as a return type

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys,
 Its all bcz really my overlook :'( . My error is I didn't have that Jquery file :p Really sorry for this silly mistake. Thanks for all your answers buds.